# postgreSQL where not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 5 table

```
psa_aso_target  psa_aso_branch    psa_aso_targetdetails  psa_aso_dept
--------------  ---------------   ---------------------  ------------
target_id[PK]   branch_id[PK]     target_id[FK]          dept_id[PK]
branch_id[FK]   branch_desc[FK]   dept_id[FK]            dept_desc
                                  grade_id[FK]

psa_aso_grade
-------------
grade_id
grade_code
```

and this is example data of my table

```
psa_aso_branch  psa_aso_dept psa_aso_grade  psa_aso_target
b1 | Jakarta    d1 | Dept1   g1 | 101       t1 | b2
b2 | Surabaya   d2 | Dept2   g2 | 201       t2 | b3
b3 | Semarang   d3 | Dept3   g3 | 301
                             g4 | 401
                             g5 | 501

psa_aso_targetdetails
t1 | d1 | g1    t1 | d2 | g1    t2 | d3 | g3                        
t1 | d1 | g2    t1 | d2 | g2    t2 | d3 | g4                   
t1 | d1 | g3    t1 | d2 | g3                 
t1 | d1 | g4    t2 | d1 | g1                  
t1 | d1 | g5    t2 | d1 | g4
```

what query that i need to get this expected result

```
branch_id | branch_desc | dept_id | dept_desc | string_agg (grade_code)
-----------------------------------------------
b1        | Jakarta     | d1      | dept1     | g1,g2,g3,g4,g5
b1        | Jakarta     | d1      | dept2     | g1,g2,g3,g4,g5
b1        | Jakarta     | d1      | dept3     | g1,g2,g3,g4,g5 
b2        | Surabaya    | d2      | dept2     | g4,g5
b2        | Surabaya    | d2      | dept3     | g1,g2,g3,g4,g5
b3        | Semarang    | d2      | dept3     | g2,g3,g5
b3        | Semarang    | d2      | dept3     | g1,g2,g3,g4,g5
b3        | Semarang    | d2      | dept3     | g1,g2,g5
```

the explanation is : I want to select all branch and department with grade that has been not yet picked on psa_aso_targetdetails (on that branch and department) so that the output is above

Comment: Fix your question.  You start with "four" tables, but have "five".  And the grades have no connections to the other tables.

Comment: already fixed sir @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select t1.branch_id,t1.branch_desc,t4.dept_id, t4.dept_desc, string_agg (grade_code)
from psa_aso_branch t1
join psa_aso_target t2 on t1.branch_id = t2.branch_id
join psa_aso_targetdetails t3 on on t3.target_id = t1.target_id
join psa_aso_dept t4 on t4.dept_id = t3.dept_id
join psa_aso_grade t5 on t5.grade_id = t3.grade_id
group by t1.branch_id,t1.branch_desc,t4.dept_id, t4.dept_desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your query will select branch,department that the grade has already been used, what i want is to show all grade that not been used yet on targetdetails, btw your code has some flaw (line 1: string_agg(t5.grade_code, ',') | line 4 ....t3 on t3.target_id = t2.target_id